# Is there a possible way to add a new row and insert updated formula?

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for some help on a small project of mine. VBA coding is not my thing and just started to learn now at a way later age than I'd like.

Backstory:
I work in Business Management and look at a lot of project management finances. I see that it is pretty slow to add a new formula and then drag down the updated formula.
I have been looking how to add a new row that is continuous on top of adding a Concatenate formula to provide a unique ID.
I have done some research and found a file that will be able to add rows with a value of +1 for every row.

Goal(s):

Main Objective-
If someone can help me to update the formula (Concatenate formula on column E), it is a straight copy and paste at this moment so it is not updating based on the new row. Can someone help me revise the code?

Secondary Objective-
Also, it may be a reach but is there code out already that can ask for a text box of some sort to provide more than one new row with the appropriate formulas being copied as well?

Thank you for the help!

Please see the code below:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim Iint As Integer
     
    Set wsS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRows = wsS1.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
     
    If wsS1.Range("B5").Value = "" Then
        wsS1.Range("B5").Value = 1
        wsS1.Range("G5").Formula = "=IF(AND(D4=""""),"""",IF(AND(D4<>""""),$E4))"
        wsS1.Rows(4).EntireRow.Copy
        wsS1.Rows(5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Selection.Font.Bold = False
        Rows(5).RowHeight = 12.75

    End If
    
    For Iint = 5 To lRows
        If wsS1.Range("B" & Iint + 1).Value = "" Then
            wsS1.Rows(Iint).EntireRow.Copy
            wsS1.Rows(Iint + 1).PasteSpecial xlFormats
            wsS1.Rows(Iint + 1).PasteSpecial xlFormula
            wsS1.Range("G" & Iint + 1).Formula = wsS1.Range("G" & Iint).Formula
            wsS1.Range("C" & Iint + 1).Formula = wsS1.Range("C" & Iint).Formula
            wsS1.Range("D" & Iint + 1).Formula = wsS1.Range("D" & Iint).Formula
            wsS1.Range("E" & Iint + 1).Formula = wsS1.Range("E" & Iint).Formula
            wsS1.Range("B" & Iint + 1).Value = wsS1.Range("B" & Iint).Value + 1
        End If
    Next Iint

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi sorry, it says edited but I don't know if you edited the post or the code on the post. Pretty new to this.

Comment: You can take the [tour] or see the [help] for how this site works. "Edited" means someone edited your post to format it correctly, make it better readable, fix typos or grammar. If you click on the "edited xx hours ago" you will see what exactly was edited. • If you ask a question make sure you show what exactly went wrong when trying to achieve your goal. We need to know where in the code you got stuck or errors (also see [ask]).